# Compare two versions in logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have two version strings and I need to compare them like the .NET `Version` type can (with awareness of Major, Minor versions, instead of just as strings) to see which one is newer. My question here is: How can I check which version string is newer in logic apps?

Is there any nicer way than the 'brute force' approach of string manipulation?

```
major = split(variables('CurrentImageVer', '.'))[0]
minor = split(variables('CurrentImageVer', '.'))[1]
```

and so on...

Comment: Not really, string manipulation will get you the result. Not sure what you thought might exist that would do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Skin, Since the versions themselves are of string type, this can be done through string manipulation. Below is something that worked for me after reproducing from my end.

For demonstration purposes I have used the below 2 versions in an array variable.

```
[
  "1.2.31",
  "1.2.30"
]
```

- Firstly, I have tried to split both the versions from the array.

  [image]
- Then I have used Condition connector to check if version 1 is greater or not than the other.

[image]

[image]

### Results

[image]

Below is the complete JSON of my logic app.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@variables('Latest Version')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Until": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Flag": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Flag",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Versions",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                "1.2.31",
                                "1.2.30"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Latest_Version": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Latest Version",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "Latest Not Found"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Split_Version1": {
                "inputs": "@split(variables('Versions')[0],'.')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Latest_Version": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Split_Version2": {
                "inputs": "@split(variables('Versions')[1],'.')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Flag": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Until": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Set_variable_2": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Latest Version",
                                    "value": "@{variables('Versions')[0]} is the latest version"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "SetVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "else": {
                            "actions": {
                                "Condition_2": {
                                    "actions": {
                                        "Set_variable": {
                                            "inputs": {
                                                "name": "Latest Version",
                                                "value": "@{variables('Versions')[1]} is the latest version"
                                            },
                                            "runAfter": {},
                                            "type": "SetVariable"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "expression": {
                                        "and": [
                                            {
                                                "less": [
                                                    "@outputs('Split_Version1')[variables('Flag')]",
                                                    "@outputs('Split_Version2')[variables('Flag')]"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "equals": [
                                                    "@variables('Latest Version')",
                                                    "Latest Not Found"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "runAfter": {},
                                    "type": "If"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "greater": [
                                        "@outputs('Split_Version1')[variables('Flag')]",
                                        "@outputs('Split_Version2')[variables('Flag')]"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "equals": [
                                        "@variables('Latest Version')",
                                        "Latest Not Found"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    },
                    "Increment_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Flag",
                            "value": 1
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Condition": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "IncrementVariable"
                    }
                },
                "expression": "@equals(variables('Flag'), length(outputs('Split_Version1')))",
                "limit": {
                    "count": 60,
                    "timeout": "PT1H"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Split_Version1": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ],
                    "Split_Version2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Until"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```